# SQL Server 2008 pivot text column too large

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am trying to get the data from a MNR table but need to convert some fields in the rows to columns. I'm using PIVOT and get almost what I want but find no way to avoid the issue with long texts (over 128 char that seems to be the limit). This is a database I have not created and my boss is chasing me on this although he wants no changes to be made (no procedures or similar).

Below is the query I have:

```
SELECT [Site]
      ,PersonId
      ,VisitId
      ,RepeatNumber
      ,[Conmoción medular (sin signos detectables de lesión)]
      ,[Edema]
      ,[Contusión hemorrágica]
      ,[Hematoma medular]
      ,[Transección medular]
      ,[Hematoma epidural]
  FROM SELECT * FROM MNR_Database
  PIVOT (Max(RMLES) FOR RMLes IN([Conmoción medular (sin signos detectables de lesión)],[Edema],[Contusión hemorrágica],[Hematoma medular],[Transección medular],[Hematoma epidural])) Tab2
```

The six fields between [] are the headers of the new columns. The problem is that some of these are texts longer than 128 chars and don't know if there is something similar to "LIKE" for PIVOT.

Along with these I would like to get a "yes/no" in each of these columns. Hope you can help me.

Comment: A column can't have a name over 128 characters.

Comment: `PIVOT` is a nicety; queries can always be rewritten to do without it (`[x] = case when value = 'x' then 1 else 0 end, [y] = case when value = 'y' then 1 else 0 end`, then aggregate those values). You can sneak a `LIKE` or `LEFT` in there rather than an `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to do a pivot without using the `Pivot` operator, and in my opinion, it has enough advantages in terms of performance and flexibility that I tend to use it as my default pattern.  In your case it gives the flexibility to use a like statement and should not give any issues with a character length in the rmles column.

```
select      [Site],
            PersonId,
            VisitId,
            RepeatNumber,

            [Conmoción medular (sin signos detectables de lesión)] = 
                max(case when rmles like '%Conmoción medular (sin signos detectables de lesión)%' then 'Y' else 'N' end),

            Edema = max(case when rmles like '%Edema%' then 'Y' else 'N' end),
            [Contusión hemorrágica] = max(case when rmles like '%Contusión hemorrágica%' then 'Y' else 'N' end),
            [Hematoma medular] = max(case when rmles like '%Hematoma medular%' then 'Y' else 'N' end),
            [Transección medular] = max(case when rmles like '%Transección medular%' then 'Y' else 'N' end),
            [Hematoma epidural] = max(case when rmles like '%Hematoma epidural%' then 'Y' else 'N' end)

from        mnr_database -- but you mean 'table', right?
group by    [Site],
            PersonId,
            VisitId,
            RepeatNumber
```

I would probably make 'Conmoción medular' the title of the first pivoted column, even though it picks up a larger text, but that's up to you.

More importantly, I would question your underlying design.  If these are relevant points of data, don't capture them via a text field.

Comment: Thank you so much! This made my day. 
Yes,  'Conmoción medular' is the title of the first pivoted column, just forgot to change it,
Yes, I meant table.
About the design, the front end we work on is a too enclosed environment that does not allow much manipulating, and when you must work with the database you find it is a mess.
Many thanks you again.